# r.neighbors produces no output

Tags: grass-gis

I am running

```
r.neighbors --overwrite --verbose input=bf03pits@PERMANENT output=bf03pitsdenoise method=mode size=5
```

in the GRASS GUI using the `r.neighbors` dialog.

bf03pits has 3955848 all with values either 0 or 1.

When I run `r.neighbors` the result has 1 cell with a range of `-nan` to `-nan`.

Yet the output shows no errors.

Why might `r.neighbors` be failing? How can I go about doing what I want?

Comment: Have you set the region to match your input raster? i.e. `g.region rast=bf03pits`

Comment: @si_2012, that was absolutely the problem. Please write your comment up as an answer so I can accept it. Was there some obvious way I should have known that?

Comment: Answer written up. There's no obvious way to know this, but with Grass its essential to pay close attention to the region settings. Before running commands, type `g.region -p` in the command line to make sure the settings are as you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Grass, this sort of problem occurs when the region settings don't match the input raster. Try setting the region to the input raster, i.e. `g.region rast=bf03pits`, before running `r.neighbors`.

Answer (score 0):

In GRASS v. 7.x the solution is still the same (we must match region setting with the raster extent) but the option has changed : `g.region raster=bf03pits`